# Переход между TextBox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

Есть два TextBox:

```
<TextBox Padding="1" Margin="2" FontSize="35" Name="Cell1" TextAlignment="Center" PreviewKeyDown="Cell1_PreviewKeyDown"/>
<TextBox Padding="1" Margin="2" FontSize="35" Name="Cell2" TextAlignment="Center" PreviewKeyDown="Cell2_PreviewKeyDown"/>
```

Через PreviewKeyDown происходит перемещение курсора из одного TextBox в другой после нажатия кнопки "пробел":

```
private void Cell21_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{ 
   if (e.Key == Key.Space) 
        Cell22.Focus(); 
}
private void Cell22_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{ 
   if (e.Key == Key.Space) 
        Cell21.Focus(); 
}
```

При нажатии "пробел", курсор перемещается в TextBox и добавляет пробел.

Можно ли как-то удалять этот пробел сразу после того, как курсор переместился?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пометьте событие в обработчиках как отработанное сразу после задания фокуса:

```
private void Cell1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Space)
        Cell2.Focus();
    e.Handled = true;
}
private void Cell2_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Space)
        Cell1.Focus();
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Добавил дополнительный вопрос

Comment: @A.Hall, новый вопрос задайте отдельно. А этот вопрос откатите к предыдущей версии.

Comment: @A.Hall: После того, как на ваш вопрос дан ответ, изменять смысл вопроса нельзя, потому что это превращает правильный ответ в неправильный или неполный.

Comment: Понял. Задал новый вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/806363/previewkeydown-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-grid-%D0%B8-textbox