# PreviewKeyDown для Grid и TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

Есть TextBox-ы в одном Grid. По атрибуту PreviewKeyDown в TextBox перемещается курсор из одного TextBox в другой:

```
private void Cell21_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{ 
   if (e.Key == Key.Space) 
        Cell22.Focus();
        e.Handled = true; 
}
private void Cell22_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{ 
   if (e.Key == Key.Space) 
        Cell21.Focus(); 
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

Есть ли способ добавить атрибут PreviewKeyDown к этому Grid, чтобы не прописывать команды в каждом методе отдельно, а просто в одном методе добавить List из TextBox-ов и перемещать курсор в цикле?

```
<Grid Name="FirstGrid" PreviewKeyDown="FirstGrid_PreviewKeyDown">
<TextBox Padding="1" Margin="2" FontSize="35" Name="Cell1" TextAlignment="Center" PreviewKeyDown="Cell1_PreviewKeyDown"/>
<TextBox Padding="1" Margin="2" FontSize="35" Name="Cell2" TextAlignment="Center" PreviewKeyDown="Cell2_PreviewKeyDown"/>
</Grid>
```

Если да, то какое условие нужно добавить в if, в этом методе?

```
private void FirstGrid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   List<TextBox> firstList = new List<TextBox> { Cell1, Cell2 };

   for (int i = 0; i < firstList.Count; i++) { 
       if (e.Key == Key.Space) { 
          firstList[i].Focus(); 
          e.Handled = true; 
       } 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы внутри одного контейнера фокус перемещался циклически, необходимо установить Attached Property `KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation`:

```
<Grid KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle">
    ...
</Grid>
```

Для передачи фокуса *следующему элементу* используйте метод `MoveFocus`:

```
TextBox.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
```

Для того, чтобы передавать фокус по пробелу, как вам ответили в предыдущем вопросе, необходимо обрабатывать событие `PreviewKeyDown`, если вам нужно это сделать более чем в одном контроле, то правильнее всего будет написать соответствующее *поведение* для контрола. Для этого подключите библиотеку System.Windows.Interactivity.dll одним из способов, описанных в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/726434/218063) и напишите такой класс:

```
public class SpaceNavigationBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.PreviewKeyDown += OnPreviewKeyDown;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.PreviewKeyDown -= OnPreviewKeyDown;
    }

    private void OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key != Key.Space) return;
        AssociatedObject.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Теперь, в разметке окна подключите пространство имен:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

Проверяем:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle">
        <TextBox>
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <local:SpaceNavigationBehavior/>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </TextBox>

        <TextBox>
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <local:SpaceNavigationBehavior/>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </TextBox>
    </StackPanel>

    <TextBox>
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <local:SpaceNavigationBehavior/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Запустите проект и убедитесь, что фокус (как по пробелу, так и по Tab) перемещается циклически между первыми двумя TextBox'ами.

К сожалению AP `Interaction.Behaviors` не имеет сеттера, поэтому невозможно установить ему значение в стиле для всех TextBox сразу. Поэтому я написал вот такое (не самое лучшее, но рабочее) решение:

```
public static class BehaviorEx
{
    public static Type GetBehavior(DependencyObject obj)
        => (Type)obj.GetValue(BehaviorProperty);

    public static void SetBehavior(DependencyObject obj, Type value)
        => obj.SetValue(BehaviorProperty, value);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BehaviorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Behavior", typeof(Type), typeof(BehaviorEx),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, OnBehaviorChanged));

    private static void OnBehaviorChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var type = (Type)e.NewValue;
        var collection = Interaction.GetBehaviors(d);
        if (e.NewValue != null)
        {
            var behavior = (Behavior)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            collection.Add(behavior);
        }
    }
}
```

После чего разметку можно сократить до такой:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="local:BehaviorEx.Behavior" Value="local:SpaceNavigationBehavior"/>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <StackPanel KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle">
        <TextBox/>
        <TextBox/>
    </StackPanel>
    <TextBox/>
</StackPanel>
```

Работает она так же, как и предыдущая.

Comment: Я поэкспериментировал с `KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation`, но так и не увидел разницы работы, для чего он?

Comment: Вернее я понимаю для чего он, но почему то он не работает

Comment: @Gardes, поместите в панель не текстбоксы, а, например, кнопки и попробуйте перемещать фокус стрелками на клавиатуре

Comment: Все верно, с кнопками работает, с TextBox никак.

Comment: @Gardes, ну тексбокс в этом плане особенный, у вас же должна быть возможность перемещать курсор внутри него

Comment: Логично) Просто я к тому что это свойство никак не влияет на пробел, а так конечно оно имеет право быть в ответе, спасибо за информацию!

Comment: Пишет, что SpaceNavigationBehavior не существует в пространстве имён, хотя библиотеку подключил и добавил пространство имён в разметке. Ещё вопрос: как использовать метод MoveFocus?

Comment: @A.Hall, после того, как добавили класс SpaceNavigationBehavior, перед написанием разметки скомпилируйте проект.

Comment: Сделал, не помогло. Правильно ли я понимаю, что PreviewKeyDown у TextBox нет? Как использовать метод MoveFocus?

Comment: @A.Hall, а MoveFocus используется в SpaceNavigationBehavior.OnPreviewKeyDown. AssociatedObject это тот объект, который ассоциирован с этим поведением, т.е. наш TextBox

Comment: @A.Hall, а в каком пространстве имен у вас лежит класс SpaceNavigationBehavior? "Правильно ли я понимаю, что PreviewKeyDown у TextBox нет?" - как нету, именно на него мы и подписываемся в поведении.

Comment: @A.Hall, первые 2 куска кода это просто информация, а дальше уже идет пример. Просто попробуйте начать с третьего куска: подключите библиотеку, добавьте класс, скомпилируйте проект, добавьте разметку. Должно всё сработать. Без компиляции класса дизайнер его не увидит, это описано в этом ответе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/618507/218063 После того как это заработает, можно будет добавить класс BehaviorEx, скомпилировать еще раз и изменить разметку как написано в последнем куске кода. Отпишитесь о результатах.

Comment: В новой разметке пишет: префикс пространства имен "c" не определен

Comment: @A.Hall, там не `c`, а `local`. Вроде давно исправил.

Comment: В методе Cell_PreviewKeyDown, на который ссылаются все TextBox через PreviewKeyDown пишет ошибку: "Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства "FrameworkElement.MoveFocus(TraversalRequest)" требуется ссылка на объект."

Comment: @A.Hall, покажите как вы вызываете `MoveFocus`. У вас мой код заработал?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75240/discussion-between-a-hall-and--nop).

Answer (score 2):

Если у вас будет всего 2 TextBox, как в вопросе, то достаточно будет сделать так:

```
bool firstCellIsFocused = true;

private void FirstGrid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{ 
    if (e.Key == Key.Space) 
    { 
        if (firstCellIsFocued)
        {
            Cell2.Focus();                 
        }
        else 
        {
            Cell1.Focus();                
        }
        e.Handled = true; 
        firstCellIsFocued = !firstCellIsFocued;
    } 
}
```

---

**UPD**

Если TextBox много, то лучше в каждом TextBox подписаться на событие `PreviewKeyDown`

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox PreviewKeyDown="Cell_PreviewKeyDown"/>
    <TextBox PreviewKeyDown="Cell_PreviewKeyDown"/>
    <TextBox PreviewKeyDown="Cell_PreviewKeyDown"/>
</StackPanel>
```

и перемещать фокус как сказано в ответе у [@Андрей NOP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/218063/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9-nop):

```
private void Cell_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Space)
    {
        TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;
        tb.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
        e.Handled = true;
    }           
}
```

Comment: А если TextBox-ов много, можно как-то использовать цикл, как в вопросе?

Comment: Вы хотите менять фокус по кругу, правильно?

Comment: Да, менять фокус по кругу.

Comment: Изменение фокуса по `Tab`, вам такой эффект нужен?

Comment: Нет, именно по Space, это имеет значение?

Comment: @A.Hall, Обновил

Comment: Да, отлично. Если у меня два Grid и мне нужно круг был ещё и между ними. Т.е. сначала все TextBox в одном Grid, потом все TextBox в другом, затем опять по кругу?

Comment: Оберните оба Grid в еще один и у него задайте KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation как в моем ответе. @A.Hall